# jQuery Tools range input demo does not work for my Chrome or Firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

I was trying [this demo](http://jquerytools.org/demos/rangeinput/index.html) out locally. If succeeded I should be able to see something like [this](http://jquerytools.org/demos/rangeinput/index.htm). However, all I saw was an editable box which says "NaN".

Here is what I have tried:

1. I copied the code given by [their web page](http://jquerytools.org/demos/rangeinput/index.html) and saved it as a local html file. I opened it with Chrome and Firefox, but instead of seeing the scrollbar, I just saw a white box.
2. I went to their [standalone demo](http://jquerytools.org/demos/rangeinput/index.htm) and did an "View Page Source" with Chrome. I copied the entire html file, saved it locally, and opened it in Chrome and Firefox. The result is still the same.

Here is my current local html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!--
   This is a jQuery Tools standalone demo. Feel free to copy/paste.
   http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/

   Do *not* reference CSS files and images from flowplayer.org when in
   production Enjoy!
-->
<head>
  <title>jQuery Tools standalone demo</title>

    <!-- include the Tools -->
  <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>

  <!-- standalone page styling (can be removed) -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/media/img/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="/media/css/standalone.css"/>

    <!-- rangeinput styling -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="/media/css/rangeinput/skin1.css"/>
</head>
<body>  <!-- HTML5 range input -->
  <input type="range" name="test" min="100" max="300" value="150" />

  <!-- make it happen -->
  <script>
    $(":range").rangeinput();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When downloading the page, any HTML structure changes done by scripts are saved with in your file. If you look the request for the *index.html* file in your Network tab of the developer console, you can see that the content of the requested file differs from the actual downloaded file (besides scripts and stylesheets urls).

Copy the contents of the body **from the requested *index.html*** and your example will start working locally.

Comment: I didn't get it. Sorry, I have 0 experience in web development. I tried copying both the demo page and their standalone demo page, and I was able to see some text, links, boxes and pictures but nothing is stylized. I've double-checked the code that I copied & pasted, and they are the same with the example code... I am starting to think that maybe CSS is not linked in properly...

Comment: If you download the page with "Save page as" then you will get updated CSS links, but have to manually replace the content of the body element. On the HTML you added to your post you have the opossite problem, the HTML is ok but the linked CSS is wrong. I would suggest downloading the page with the conventional "Save page as" method, and then edit it and replace the body element with the one from the HTML you posted here.

Comment: Yes this solved my problem. When I use "Save page as" method, the href to jQuery tools and css files are no longer "http://..." but a reference to my local downloaded files such as "./jQuery Tools standalone demo_files/standalone.css". So after download, the style is correct but the body does not work. And yes, after body is updated, it did work! Thanks!